# ActiveX component changes back to UI thread

Tags: .net, activex, threadpool

In a .NET application, I'm using a third-party ActiveX control to connect to a device. This components has no UI so I can use from a Windows App, a Console App or a Windows Service. The problem is that it behaves differently based on the application type.

Using it from a Console Application (or Windows Service):

1. I call a component method using a ThreadPool, that means, in a thread other than the main one.
2. The method is executed in the same thread. (as expected)
3. The method callback is running in the same thread. (as expected)

However, when using it from a Windows Application:

1. I *call* a component method using a ThreadPool, that means, in a thread other than the UI one.
   --> At this point the ActiveX control seems to change to the UI thread.
2. The method is executed in the UI thread (I see the UI blocking!)
3. The method callback is running in the UI thread.

Is there any way to isolated the component so the calls get executed in a thread other than the UI one?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be treating the ActiveX control as a UI control.  Only a comment.  Does the control have any UI component?

Comment: It does not (almost sure). I'm reading that I should create a thread in STA mode, not sure how to instantiate the component there tough.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search and reading I was able to make it work. Here's the code I used, with some comments. To learn more search Google for ".net Com thread sta" or similar.

```
// COM objects will always execute in the same thread where they were created, 
// so it's better to create them in another thread (that must be alive as long as the object
// exists) to avoid blocking the UI thread.
var thread = new Thread(CreateComponent);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
threads.Add(thread);

thread.Start("optional parameters");


private void CreateComponent(object obj)
{
    var parameters = obj as string;

    // Create the COM object here
    var component = new CreateYourCOMComponent(parameters);

    // You might want to catch all unhandled exceptions too
    Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;

    // Once the object is created, the thread must be alive during 
    // the whole time the COM object remains alive. The Application.Run 
    // will pump the messages required for COM and prevent the thread for exiting.
    Application.Run();
}
```